# Hosting .NET Web Api in Firebase

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to host .NET Web Api project in Firebase hosting module? Would be a great way of changing my current provider.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firebase Hosting is for serving static assets only (HTML, JS, CSS, images, video, etc...).

You can't run any server code like the .NET Web API.

But if you're looking for guidance on using Firebase with Web API, you can check out these two repos:

https://github.com/davideast/FirebaseAuth-WebApi/
https://github.com/davideast/FirebaseAuth.Web

The first shows how to authenticate Web API against a Firebase database ([using a Filter](https://github.com/davideast/FirebaseAuth-WebApi/blob/master/FirebaseAuth.Api/Filters/DecodeJWT.cs)), and the second is the client side app (written in Angular).

Comment: The sad part is that I wanted to have both Web Api and the angular site itself in Firebase. Unfortunately I don't see them both working in Firebase so I have to go for another solution (maybe azure for Web Api or something similar and Firebase for Angular part). Any suggestions how to do this best?

Comment: You can host Web API anywhere and still use Firebase. You don't have to use Firebase Hosting to use the Firebase database.

Comment: That of course, but I was looking at the optimal solution. Think I will stick with Azure for Web Api and Firebase for angular part. Thanks!